# PostgreSQL Service unexpectedly closing

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, devart, enterprisedb

using `PostgreSQL 9.2` on `Windows Xp(RAM 4GB)` sometimes the Database service is closing unexpectedly.

am new in PostgreSQL Database, So i cannot figure out the reason behind it, can any one help me ?!

1. [log 1](http://pastebin.com/tNPwxM1B)
2. [log 2](http://pastebin.com/Y3YwWMr0)

*Current Backend Access config*(pg_hba.conf)

```
host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0   trust
```

*Postgresql.conf Settings*

```
effective_cache_size  =  131072
lc_messages  =  English_United States.1252
lc_monetary  =  English_United States.1252
lc_numeric  =  English_United States.1252
lc_time  =  English_United States.1252
listen_addresses  =  *
log_destination  =  stderr
log_line_prefix  =  %t 
log_timezone  =  Asia/Calcutta
logging_collector  =  on
max_connections  =  10000
max_files_per_process  =  1000
port  =  5432
restart_after_crash  =  on
shared_buffers  =  131072
temp_buffers  =  131072
TimeZone  =  Asia/Calcutta
work_mem  =  1048576
```

Comment: Check your system event log what your OS has to say about this...

Comment: Why do you think you can support 10,000 simultaneous connections? What do you think would happen if you actually tried to run 10,000 queries all at once? Anyway, read this page for the why http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows#I_cannot_run_with_more_than_about_125_connections_at_once.2C_despite_having_capable_hardware